# Application time out when accessing the specific report

Tags: java, oracle11g, timeout

```
public HashMap generateMsgFiveDaysCompltdReport(
    final SearchCriteria msgCriteria,
    String[] queueselected, 
    boolean flag) throws SQLException {
    HashMap msgInitiatedData = null;    

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("generateMsgInitiatedReport of ReportsDelegate  - start");
    }    

    logReportRun("Requested", msgCriteria.getReportName(),
            msgCriteria.getStartDate(), msgCriteria.getEndDate(),
            msgCriteria.getQueueDesc(), "", msgCriteria.getProfileId());
    TimeTracker tt = new TimeTracker();
    tt.start();
    msgInitiatedData = reportsDAO.generateMsgFiveDaysCompltdReport(msgCriteria, queueselected,flag);
    tt.stop();
    String totalTime = Long.toString(tt.getTotalTime());
    logReportRun("Completed", msgCriteria.getReportName(),
            msgCriteria.getStartDate(), msgCriteria.getEndDate(),
            msgCriteria.getQueueDesc(), totalTime, msgCriteria.getProfileId());  

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.info("generateMsgInitiatedReport-End");
    }

    return msgInitiatedData;
}
```

Application calling this method and once after completion of reportsDAO.generateMsgFiveDaysCompltdReport, it shows how much time it took to execute. In the logs i could see for 68-75 seconds. However it keeps calling even this methode repeatedly causing the application timeout. I know its calling repeatedly because of logger statements "Requested " and "Completed " before and after  reportsDAO.generateMsgFiveDaysCompltdReport. is it because of thread hung or DB connection issues? I am not able to replicate the same issue in SIT/UAT or DEV environemnt.

Logs:

```
[12/12/16 15:32:21:983 EST] 00000049 SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:32:21,983 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.delegate.ReportsDelegate:618) - Requested the report Messages+Turnaround+in+Business+Days+by+NPI+or+Queue for input criteria [ProfileId:VPurimetla2207, Start Date: 12%2F08%2F2016, End Date: 12%2F09%2F2016, Selected Queue: null]  
[12/12/16 15:32:28:463 EST] 0000004f SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:32:28,460 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.delegate.ReportsDelegate:618) - Completed the report Messages+Turnaround+in+Business+Days+by+NPI+or+Queue for input criteria [ProfileId:VPurimetla2207, Start Date: 12%2F08%2F2016, End Date: 12%2F09%2F2016, Selected Queue: null] and total time taken is: 66.67 Sec.  
[12/12/16 15:32:57:293 EST] 0000004a SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:32:57,292 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.action.ValidateUserAction:164) - User has logged on%0A+%28CustomInfo+%3A+%29%0A+%5Brequest+params%3A+none%5D%0A+%3Cuser%3A+HHarriman2642%3E+%7BsessionId%3A+cEKjYeADwPUwmrNRtAoTR5T%7D  
[12/12/16 15:33:00:466 EST] 0000004a SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:33:00,465 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.dao.QuestionDAO:641) - QuestionDAO.sendClaimsMessage: ICN=ICN%23006390263 msgId=14172673 queueId=202 systemName=BXWGS patientID=LCB863763363  
[12/12/16 15:33:11:959 EST] 0000004f SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:33:11,958 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.dao.QuestionDAO:641) - QuestionDAO.sendClaimsMessage: ICN=ICN%23006390267 msgId=14172677 queueId=90 systemName=NASCOPAR patientID=UGG9219580610001  
[12/12/16 15:33:22:147 EST] 0000004a SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:33:22,147 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.delegate.ReportsDelegate:618) - Requested the report Messages+Turnaround+in+Business+Days+by+NPI+or+Queue for input criteria [ProfileId:VPurimetla2207, Start Date: 12%2F08%2F2016, End Date: 12%2F09%2F2016, Selected Queue: null]  
[12/12/16 15:33:24:478 EST] 00000049 SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:33:24,477 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.delegate.ReportsDelegate:618) - Completed the report Messages+Turnaround+in+Business+Days+by+NPI+or+Queue for input criteria [ProfileId:VPurimetla2207, Start Date: 12%2F08%2F2016, End Date: 12%2F09%2F2016, Selected Queue: null] and total time taken is: 62.49 Sec.  
[12/12/16 15:33:27:687 EST] 00000049 SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:33:27,687 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.dao.QuestionDAO:641) - QuestionDAO.sendClaimsMessage: ICN=ICN%23006390268 msgId=14172681 queueId=502 systemName=SEVA patientID=YRZ958M62248  
[12/12/16 15:34:22:245 EST] 0000003a SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:34:22,244 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.delegate.ReportsDelegate:618) - Requested the report Messages+Turnaround+in+Business+Days+by+NPI+or+Queue for input criteria [ProfileId:VPurimetla2207, Start Date: 12%2F08%2F2016, End Date: 12%2F09%2F2016, Selected Queue: null]  
[12/12/16 15:34:28:404 EST] 0000004a SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:34:28,404 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.delegate.ReportsDelegate:618) - Completed the report Messages+Turnaround+in+Business+Days+by+NPI+or+Queue for input criteria [ProfileId:VPurimetla2207, Start Date: 12%2F08%2F2016, End Date: 12%2F09%2F2016, Selected Queue: null] and total time taken is: 66.26 Sec.  
[12/12/16 15:34:50:717 EST] 0000004f SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:34:50,716 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.action.ValidateUserMPPSSOAction:147) - prevProfileID hamde2pfs%23 found for DHamlin8008  
[12/12/16 15:34:50:720 EST] 0000004f SystemOut     O 12/12/2016 15:34:50,719 INFO  (com.anthem.central.sm.action.ValidateUserMPPSSOAction:212) - User has logged on%0A+%28CustomInfo+%3A+%29%0A+%5Brequest+params%3A+TargetXML%3DPD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48VXNlcj48UHJvdmlkZXJTdGF0ZT5DQTwvUHJvdmlkZXJTdGF0ZT48U1NPSWQ%2BYWthNDAwMzEzODE0MzQ8L1NTT0lkPjxIZWFsdGhQbGFuVXNlcklkPmhhbWRlMnBmczwvSGVhbHRoUGxhblVzZXJJZD48Um9sZT5VU0VSPC9Sb2xlPjxEZWVwbGlua0lkPjwvRGVlcGxpbmtJZD48L1VzZXI%2B%2C+FirstName%3DY807Mmp0%2BuxqPSZGBmCLdQ%3D%3D%2C+LastName%3D2%2Fi%2BFEH6qyKDYDHatADmNA%3D%3D%2C+Email%3DLFKtdhJnLi8tV4k6hkDnO2XTL%2F8GigkELIsfpFEoxvg%3D%5D%0A+%3Cuser%3A+DHamlin8008%3E+%7BsessionId%3A+4sf5VL9IA5I-PF8c3Wgpzw8%7D
```

Comment: What invokes this code?  Is the stack the same for all calls?  Does the client have an auto-retry if no response in say 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

> However it keeps calling even this methode repeatedly causing the application timeout. I know its calling repeatedly because of logger statements "Requested " and "Completed " before and after reportsDAO.generateMsgFiveDaysCompltdReport.

This indicates that something is calling your generateMsgFiveDaysCompltdReport method multiple times. With what you have given us, it isn't possible to tell you why this might be. Are you certain that the code that invokes your method isn't in the middle of some loop or a recursive statement?

If you have a debugger attached to your application, inspecting the call stack should tip you off to where the excessive invocations are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting it very late. I am new to StackOverflow

Cause: I solved the issue myself but forgot to post it here, so doing it now. There is a ServerIOTimeout setting in Websphere set to 60s, which causes the webserver to initiate the request again if it has not received the response within 60s. Since my request contains the database queries which took more approximately around 70s causing the issue. Couldn't replicate the issue in lower environments as the queries were executing in 20s (data volume is very less)

Solution: increased the serverIOtimeout setting to 180s solved it.